# es6 how to use default parameters that go before non-default parameters?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-value

I am a bit rusty on default parameters, and I am wondering how can I use a default value for a parameter if it goes before parameters without defaults?

In the [example from Redux.js](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) below, when will the default value `{}` for the `state` parameter be useful? (since you can't default the next parameter)?

```
const todo = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    //...

    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state
      }

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        completed: !state.completed
      })

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense. The default parameters must come last. For that reason in some compiled languages it's even denied.

Comment: Why can't you "*default the next parameter*"?

Comment: @RobG I didn't come up with the example. I am just trying to understand a use case in Redux tutorial.

Comment: @zerkms see my answer below to understand the redux use case.

Comment: @cquezel my comment was not about whether it technically is possible or not, but about the design perspective of doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usage in question is specific to `redux.js`. The default value for the first parameter is generally useless in function calls because of the second parameter without default.

However, as said earlier in the same tutorial [about Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html):

> **Redux will call our reducer with an undefined state for the first
>   time**. This is our chance to return the initial state of our app:

```
function todoApp(state, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return initialState
  }
  //...
  return state
}
```

So the 1st parameter isn't really omitted here. Redux is supplying `undefined` as its value on initialization. It is only in this case, the tutorial used default arguments syntax as a shortcut:

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  //...
  return state
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The defaults are called when the parameter is `undefined`:

```
todo(undefined, { type: 'WHATEVER' });
```

To prevent the need for setting `undefined`s when calling the function, I prefer to destructure an object with defaults. Using an object make the order of the params irrelevant.

```
todo({ state = {}, action } = {}) => {};
```

Comment: The second suggestion is even worse actually.

Comment: The type system yells about possibly bad design, but instead of fixing it you apply a workaround, pretending all is good.

Comment: Isn't this just passing one argument to the function?

Comment: @smac89 it is passing 2 arguments: the state and the action. Those are 2 different concepts in the application domain.

Comment: @zerkms - I'm using this pattern to get param with meaningful name , and break the need to remember order. On the way it also fixes the bad design :)

Comment: @OriDrori "let's put everything in a large untyped object" is not a fix surely :-) If you have so many parameters you struggle to remember the order - your function has too many parameters. It's a signal that the function knows and does too much.

Comment: @zerkms - javascript is untyped, and we use the tools we've got. Using flow or typescript, etc... you can type both the object, and the params.

Comment: @OriDrori just because JS is untyped does not mean one should design worse functions signatures than they could. 2 untyped parameters is more readable and easier to understand than a single object. I write JS as if it was strictly typed. It is convenient.

Comment: @zerkms - an object with meaningful property names is better than remembering the order, especially in an weakly typed system. In addition, when you want to add a 3rd param, it's even easier to do. In addition, in JS it's better than passing undefineds (used in this redux reducer). It's a very common pattern in react - for example prop types in react stateless components.

Comment: @OriDrori yep, what considered an antipattern everywhere - is fine in JS (and even promoted by high rep users). No wondering the development world laughs at JS and JS developers. :-) I'm not insisting on it though, people are free to write their code any way they like.

Comment: @zerkms - a friend of mine described JS developers as suffering from the Stockholm Syndrome :) Sometimes I agree, sometimes not. In this case I find the name params better than the ordered ones. Anyhow, here is a good (JS) lecture about API design, that talks about [Param's Traps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-ux7GIGFBo#t=12m45s), and this pattern that solves them.

Comment: @Ori I still think you're wrong about this, yet my comment is unnecessarily rude, sorry.

Comment: @ftor - no worries. Disagreements create interesting discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameter has to come last i dont think there is a direct way to make them come before other parameters however you can use [Arguments Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to achieve something like this.

e.g

```
function myFunction(){
  var firstParam , secondParam;
  if(arguments.length === 0){
     console.log("no input");
     return;
  }
  if(arguments.length === 1){
    secondParam =  arguments[0];
  }
  else{
    firstParam  =  arguments[0];
    secondParam =  arguments[1];
  }
   // you can write any logic above
   // also you can give params in function definition as well myFunction(firstParam , secondParam)
   // use params as you wish
  console.log(firstParam);
  console.log(secondParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbe to javascript but if I am not mistaken, default parameters simply replace 'undefined' parameters.

if I have a function defined as:

```
function example(var1 = false, var2, var3 = false) ...
```

This means that the following calls are all legal :

```
example(true, someVar, true);
example(true, someVar); // calls  example(true, someVar, false)
example(undefined, someVar, true); // calls example(false, someVar, true)
example(undefined, someVar); // calls example(false, someVar, true)
```

The redux framework simply passed undefined explicitly.